# Creating an employee number by adding the first 3 letters of the surname to a generated sequence of numbers starting at 001

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Employee_Seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 999
CYCLE;
```

The `Employee` table already exists so I added a column called `Employee_Seq`:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
    ADD Employee_Seq INT
```

Now what I need is to populate a new column called `Internal_Employee_No` to look something like this: `ZZZ001`, `ADB002` and so forth depending on the next 3 letters of the surname column and the numbers generated in that table where it is currently NULL

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags. Only tag the DBMS you're really using.

Comment: This is Microsoft Server Management Studio 2018, the code used works but I think I might be over thinking the question? I just need to add the first 3 letters of the surname to a number starting at 001 for the first row and then the next e.g.abc002 , bcd003 and so on

Comment: SSMS isn't an RDBMS, it's an IDE, for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for **SQL Server** - I would do it like this:

- create a new `IDENTITY` column (not a `SEQUENCE`) in the table:

  ```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
        ADD EmployeeSeqID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;
  ```
- create a **computed column** to handle the friendly ID:

  ```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
        ADD Internal_Employee_No AS 
            SUBSTRING(Surname, 1, 3) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(EmployeeSeqID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED;
  ```

So every row now has an `IDENTITY` value (starts at 1, increments by 1) and every row also contains a column `Internal_Employee_No` in your desired format.

And every time you add a new row, a new `IDENTITY` value is assigned, and the value of that `Internal_Employee_No` is computed when the row gets saved.